# Symfony 3: An exception has been thrown during the rendering

Tags: symfony, twig

The full error I am getting is this one.

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "FooBlogBundle_articles".") in "FooBlogBundle:Article:articles.html.twig".`

This is the controller, that handles the action:

```
 public function articlesAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $blog = $em->getRepository('FooBlogBundle:Blog')->find($id);

        if(!$em){
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find blog posti');
        }

        return $this->render('FooBlogBundle:Article:articles.html.twig', ['blog'=>$blog]);
    }
}
```

and the routing

```
FlickBlogBundle_articles:
    pattern:  /foo/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: FooBlogBundle:Article:articles }
    requirements:
      _method: GET
      id: \d+
```

Twig and database, are completely normal, no type or problems. But this error is kind of hard to spot, where I have gone wrong.

EDIT: Including template:

```
{% extends 'FooBlogBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
{{ blog.title }}<br/>
{{ blog.author }}<br/>
{{ blog.blog }}<br/>
{{ blog.tags }}<br/>
{{ blog.comments }}

{% endblock %}
```

The above template is located in `views/article/` it extends another templates found at `views/`
 whic is just

`{% extends 'FooBlogBundle::layout.html.twig' %}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `FooBlogBundle:Article:articles.html.twig` template you have something like `{{ path(FlickBlogBundle_articles) }}` (can not tell exactly because I do not see a template). This route requires additional parameter `id`. So change it to `{{ path(FlickBlogBundle_articles, {'id':article.id}) }}`

Comment: Hi, I will try this althouh, I am not sure how, but I have updated my question to include the templates involved

Comment: may be its on `FooBlogBundle::layout.html.twig`? Search the place where you generate link to `FlickBlogBundle_articles`

Comment: I am following this tutorial http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/doctrine-2-the-blog-model.html. And have made exactly as shown there. I can't find the `path()` method you mentioned for templates that generate data, except for the menu and form redirecting

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and in my case I forgot to set public Getters & Setters for my private foreign Key:

```
/**
 * @var Provider
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Provider")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_provider", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $fkProvider;
```

And

```
/**
 * @return Provider
 */
public function getFkProvider()
{
    return $this->fkProvider;
}

/**
 * @param Provider $fkProvider
 */
public function setFkProvider($fkProvider)
{
    $this->fkProvider = $fkProvider;
}
```